# How to use onUserInteraction in non-activity class?

Tags: android

I have an activity and non activity class, i want to get the uses Interaction from my activity class using onUserInteraction it working successfully. but I need to get the user's interaction from non-activity class.how to do that? is onUserInteraction is working in non-activity class or any other method we need to use.

NOTE: In my non-activity class not contain the XML layouts.

```
 public void onUserInteraction(){
            super.onUserInteraction();
            System.out.println("INTERACTION OCCURS : ");
}
```

if does not working means any other possible ways to capture the user interaction from no-activity class?

Comment: where you want to catch userInteractions ?

Comment: in non-activity class

Comment: but Fragment is held within the Activity. why you think you need to implement the method Fragment

Comment: non activity class are in my SDK  . .so i need to  know user interaction